# Save current stylesheet to local storage

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I know that this question has been asked, but none of the posts have helped me to get through it.

So, here is the thing - I have two stylesheets on my site. I want to save lately used stylesheet to local storage.

Switching between stylesheets works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var currentStylesheet = localStorage.getItem("stylesheet");
        document.getElementById("stylesheet").value = currentStylesheet;
        document.getElementById("stylesheet").setAttribute("href", currentStylesheet);
        }
```

I got this code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), and tried to adapt to my use, but sadly - it didn't work. I mean - it does **something**, but looks like it messes up with stylesheet and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: For a start, you shouldn't use `window.onload`. If you will load another script which use this window property, it will overwrite it. Use `addEventListener()` instead (you can polyfill it for legacy browsers).

Comment: Take a look at this question (and answer): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736997/swap-style-sheet-with-localstorage)

Comment: I have seen this before, tried to modify it, but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just forgetting about [Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem). You stated the you want to 'save' the most recent stylesheet that was used.

I think you are confusing the idea of state here. In your code sample, you read value a from localStorage, but you did not attempt to set localStorage at any point.

Let's look at a minimal example. I prepared a live demo below:

[LIVE DEMO](https://repl.it/@coltoneakins/RememberingLightAndDark)

Imagine you have these files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link id="active-stylesheet" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="switch-buttons">
        <button class="switch-buttons__light button" data-stylesheet="light.css">Go Light</button>
        <button class="switch-buttons__dark button" data-stylesheet="dark.css">Go Dark</button>
    </div>
    <h1>Light and Dark Stylesheets with Web Storage API</h1>
    <h2> See <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage">MDN Storage - Web Storage API</a>.</h2>
    <p>
      Click a button above. The style you select will be 'remembered' when you refresh this page. To reset this demo, click the 'Clear Storage' button.</p>
    <p>
        Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi? In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo.</p>
    <p>
        Etiam sit amet nisl purus, in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in! Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus, dictum at tempor commodo, ullamcorper?</p>
    <button id="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**light.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #fff0bc;
}

h1, h2, p {
  color: #363636;
}
```

**dark.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #363636;
}

h1, h2, p {
  color: #fff0bc;
}
```

**script.js**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var activeSheet = document.getElementById("active-stylesheet");
var clearStorageButton = document.getElementById("clear-storage");

// Test to see if localStorage already has a value stored
if (localStorage.getItem("lastActiveSheet")) {
     activeSheet.setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("lastActiveSheet"));
}

// Assign the event lister to each button
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", switchStyle);  
}

// Create a button to clear localStorage
clearStorageButton.addEventListener("click", clearStorage);

// Set the #active-stylesheet to be the light or dark stylesheet
function switchStyle() {
   var selectedSheet = this.getAttribute("data-stylesheet");
   activeSheet.setAttribute("href", selectedSheet);
   localStorage.setItem("lastActiveSheet", selectedSheet);
}

// Wrapper function to localStorage.clear
function clearStorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

If you want your app to remember the most recently used stylesheet, you need to store it into localStorage as a value you can use when the user visits your app again in the future.

As @Hynek had pointed out, it is not a good idea to use `window.onLoad`. So, in this example, I attached event listeners to all buttons used instead.

In this example, the page has two options to select from: a light and a dark theme for contrast. If the user selects a theme, it will be remembered the next time the page is refreshed.

The key here is the *state*. You want your app to have 'memory'. So, you need to add the functionality to *write*, *read*, and *clear* the memory. I suggest reading more through [MDN - Storage - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) to see how you can implement this. On MDN, there are even more examples too!