# How to use local storage to save a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage

I know this question has been asked several times but I've tried all of the solutions and nothing is working for me.
After a style change(switching with a toggle button between 2 different css files), I was wondering how I could save that current stylesheet when reloading the site or changing page using local storage.
This is my code for the style change:

```
function cambio() {   var c = document.getElementById("check");
var oldL = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);
console.log(oldL);
var newL = document.createElement("link");
newL.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
newL.setAttribute("type", "text/css");

  if (c.checked == true) {
    newL.setAttribute("href", "../style/style-alternate.css");
} else if (c.checked == false) {
    newL.setAttribute("href", "../style/style-base.css");   }

  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0));
document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newL, oldL); }
```

Comment: refer to this solution, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920019/save-current-stylesheet-to-local-storage

Comment: I had seen it and tried it but it didn't work :/