# Toggle between 2 stylesheets (one toggle) with local storage

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage, toggle, stylesheet

I have a toggle with and a script to switch between stylesheets but i don't know how to store the toggle state

I know there are multiple questions like this but none using a toggle and local storage with 2 stylesheets (rather css variables or something else, my css is a terrible mess and can't make those work). I'm a UI designer with some knowledge of HTML/CSS and i barely find time to learn JS.

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />


<input type="checkbox" id="tog"/>
<label for="tog" class="toggle" onclick="toggle()"></label>   


<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle() {
  var el = document.getElementById("theme");
  if (el.href.match("default.css")) {
    el.href = "dark.css";    
  }
  else {
    el.href = "default.css";  
  }
}
</script>
```

This works great but i need the toggle to be saved so it won't change back after a refresh. And from what i've read it's done with local storage but it's beyond me.

I see examples here with multiple links/buttons for each style but i can't adapt them to a toggle. I've tried. Could you help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap style sheet with localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736997/swap-style-sheet-with-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function toggle() {
        var el = document.getElementById("theme");
        var theme = (el.href === 'default.css') ? 'dark.css' : 'default.css';
        el.href = theme;
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }

    function defaultTheme() {
        var el = document.getElementById('theme');
        var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

        if (theme) {
            el.href = theme
        }
    }

    defaultTheme();

</script>
```