# How to change the css stylesheet in CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript

```
function colorChanger() {
  var len = document.getElementById("string").value.length;
  if (len < 50) {
    style1.onclick = swapStyleSheet("first_50.css");
  } else if (len > 50 && len < 100) {
    style1.onclick = swapStyleSheet("second_100.css");
  }
}
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('css_style').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

This is my code, I want it to change style sheet if the character count is `less than 50` and `more than 50 and less than 100`

My code is not working

Comment: Is the function "swapStyleSheet" one of your functions? Perhaps this question and answer is similar to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736997/swap-style-sheet-with-localstorage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript
You can check this also, you just have to load css in your head dynamically based on condition.

Comment: could you add `swapStyleSheet `function too?

Comment: @CoenieRichards i'm talking about the `if` and `else if` statement, they are not swapping the stylesheet

Comment: if the `len` equals `50` it won't work

Comment: @firatozcevahir what do you mean

Comment: I have added the `swapStyleSheet` function @Codenewbie

Comment: i guess its not his question @firatozcevahir ... and H4CKTRIX please be clear what is not working and add complete code when posting for a better understanding

Comment: @H4CKTRIK your if statements work only if len is less than 50 and more than 50. So if the len equals 50, it wont evaluate

Comment: Here:
https://codepen.io/5kyw41k3r/pen/QWKjEZj

The `len` means length of the input

Comment: May i know how many style sheets are used in your current html file ... is that only one style sheet or many ?

Comment: @Codenewbie I'm using 2 style sheets:
`first_50.css`
`second_100.css`

Comment: so based on length condition you need to change style sheets from one to other ... correct ?

Comment: @Codenewbie Exactly

Comment: what you are trrying to change in both of css ... to just check if it is necessary to change the style sheets

Comment: Ok @Codenewbie, I've figured it out, I dont need to swap whole stylesheets, thus having to reload the css into the DOM.I can just use element.classList.remove('good-tier')

Comment: glad you found that :) happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my code it is changing the stylesheet.

`````
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Change Css
    </title>
    <script lang="javascript">
        function colorChanger() {
            var len = document.getElementById("string").value.length;
            if (len < 50) {
                swapStyleSheet("first_50.css");
            } else if (len > 50 && len < 100) {
                swapStyleSheet("second_100.css");
            }
        }

        function swapStyleSheet(strName) {
            document.getElementById("cssChanger").href = strName;
        }
    </script>
    <link href="first_50.css" id="cssChanger" />
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="string" value=""></input>
    <input type="button" id='style1' value="Change Css" onclick="javascritpt:colorChanger();">
</body>

</html> ````
`````

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {

    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}

function colorChanger() {
var len = document.getElementById("string").value.length;
  if (len < 50) {
    changeCSS("first_50.css",index); // index is head tag child element index ex:0
  } else if (len > 50 && len < 100) {
    changeCSS("second_100.css",index);// index is head tag child element index ex:0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've figured it out, I dont need to swap whole stylesheets, thus having to reload the css into the DOM.I can just use element.classList.remove('good-tier')